# How do I find out why my answer was deleted?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I posted a [very acceptable answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13156546/396458), which has since been deleted with only a link to the faq page, but no reason has been given.  How can I find out why an answer was deleted?  And is it possible to have it reinstated?

Comment: Do you have a link to the question it was in?  As for, "is it possible to have it reinstated?"  Yes, it's possible.  1 mod or 3 users with 10k+ rep can undelete it if they feel that it is appropriate, possibly because you've edited the answer to fix whatever was wrong.

Comment: It's one of the [answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143904/submit-a-form-sends-email-with-data-and-redirect-to-paypal-page/13158152#13158152). The first one got flagged as Spam, and the second one got flagged because, well, it just complains about the first one getting deleted.

Comment: For the record, re-posting an answer when it's deleted is most certainly the **wrong** thing to do.

Comment: Yeah, I've been reading around here and realized that the second answer shouldn't have happened. My bad, I'm sorry.  But I felt the first one addressed the question as an updated Paypal method for selling a digital good that the user may not be aware of.  Is this not acceptable?

Comment: @AndreF Your answers should directly answer the question, everything else is unacceptable.

Comment: @Yannis To help clarify this for me, what if the question was about running an ethernet cable through solid concrete to so I could use my laptop in the basement.  Would an acceptable answer refer to wifi, or would I need to refer to a jackhammer and hammer drills?

Comment: @AndreF A question about running an ethernet cable through solid concrete would be off topic on Stack Overflow; it's not a programming question.

Comment: @Yannis - Of course, I'm just trying to get a feel for how 'on-topic' an answer needs to be.  Are offering better solutions an option, or does just the specific question need to be answered?

Comment: @AndreF You have to be *extremely careful* about promoting your own product when it is not the *exact* answer to the question asked. If your example were on-topic, it would not be appropriate to suggest WiFi, because the OP specifically asked about running ethernet through concrete - obviously not a WiFi use case

Comment: @AndreF The specific question needs to be answered. If you can suggest what you think is a better solution, you can do it after you answered the specific question as asked.

Comment: @AndreF: Use some common sense here; an answer stating "Wifi would be an acceptable alternative" would probably be OK with the community, but *"My turbo-charged, superviederflagen Wifi box will solve your problem, and it also does Julienne fries"* would just be irritating.  Especially if you post it on every question you find where it might be the slightest bit applicable.

Comment: @Robert - Thanks, that's what I was hoping to hear.  I was starting to think this place was as crazy as I am.

Comment: For the record, I'm not really disagreeing with @RobertHarvey with my immediately prior comment. The example was contrived ;)

Answer (score 20):

You didn't answer the question that was asked, but you linked to a product sales page instead.  Your post was flagged and deleted as spam.

Comment: In all fairness, there is also a link to a PayPal site: https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/ppintegrationsnate/digital-goods-express-checkout-php, which also gets the award for most horribly formatted code ever.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ That sounds like a challenge!

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ Oh, I didn't realize that was a PayPal site.  That is awful.

Comment: As I mentioned above, many programmers using PayPal aren't familiar with the PayPal Digital Goods option.  Although my answer didn't address the submit question, I felt I was offering a valid suggestion to selling his 'digital good' that he might not be aware of.  I'm trying to get a feel for this place, is answering like this out of bounds?

Comment: @BilltheLizard I didn't believe it at first, but then I saw the SSL cert.

Comment: @AndreF The question isn't even about selling digital goods.  Yes, sales promotions are out of bounds when you're not directly answering what the person is asking for.

Comment: @Bill, back to my original questions... are you saying that the problem with my answer were the links?  At this point would it be acceptable to repost my answer without the links?

Comment: @AndreF - Also, as a warning, I just went through and removed a whole bunch of answers by people you appear to be working with who all were promoting Firesage Checkout. You must disclose your affiliation with this product, per the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion or we will treat this as spam.

Comment: @AndreF No, I'm saying the problem is both that you didn't answer the question, and you posted a promotional link. It would not be acceptable to continue promoting a product if it doesn't directly answer the question being asked.

Comment: @Bill Ok, I think I'm starting to understand.  Last question... is mentioning an industry wide technology such as Paypal Digital Goods here considered promotional?

Comment: @AndreF It is fine to mention a technology, especially in comments, in order to clarify the question. Such as, "Have you considered Widget Reticulation as an option here?" But... don't go around doing that fishing for chances to post links to your product. That won't go over well, either.

Comment: Wow, systematic spamming from multiple accounts for the same product? I'm starting to question your claimed innocence/ignorance since it's clear that these accounts were trying to game the system. They're all written roughly the same.. "After much pain and suffering we finally found ### product and it saved my life! Check it out!"

Comment: @AndreF If you're here to promote your company and find all of the places where it's appropriate to post your links, then you're not welcome.  If you're here to answer questions and help others, and talking about or referring to a product that you happen to work on occasionally helps you do that, then that's okay.

Comment: @AndreF - And don't forget to mention your affiliation with the product....